# How to check element's immediate node is text?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Suggest how to check element 'simplepara' is having text immediately after it. [Template match should be from 'simplepara' as given in below XSLT]

**XML:**

```
<article>
<simplepara>Fig 1</simplepara>The text1<simplepara>Fig 2</simplepara><simplepara>Fig 3</simplepara>The text2<simplepara>Fig 4</simplepara><simplepara>Fig 5</simplepara> the text3<simplepara>Fig 5</simplepara>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="simplepara">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][text()][normalize-space()!='']">
        <xsl:comment select="'Text-Node'"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><article>
<simplepara>Fig 1</simplepara><!--Text-Node-->The text1<simplepara>Fig 2</simplepara><simplepara>Fig 3</simplepara><!--Text-Node-->The text2<simplepara>Fig 4</simplepara><simplepara>Fig 5</simplepara><!--Text-Node--> the text3<simplepara>Fig 5</simplepara>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the xpath check to use `self` axis instead of child axis:

```
following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][normalize-space()!='']
```

Comment: Good (+1).   Also note that `[normalize-space()!='']` can simplify to `[normalize-space()]`